# Vertical Seek Bar

Tags: android, android-seekbar, android-vertical-seekbar

I am using **StartPointSeekBar** from https://github.com/vashisthg/StartPointSeekBar and it is working great.

But now I need it to go vertical. I have tried several things such as:

```
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    c.rotate(-90);
    c.translate(-getHeight(),0);

    super.onDraw(c);
    }
```

and in XML:

```
android:rotation="270"
```

But nothing works.

This is horizontal **StartPointSeekBar** that I use in `portrait` mode
[image]

And this is what I get when I try to rotate it for `landscape` mode:
[image]

Any help please?

Comment: You have the source. You can contact the athor. Why did you post this question on SO?

Comment: Maybe you can use this library: https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-verticalseekbar

Comment: @Frank N. Stein I did send a question to the author, but he is not answering. So I thought maybe there is someone on SO kind enough who already did it

Comment: @Marek Rzeźniczek I will try to use some code from there and make it vertical.

Comment: @filipst I am also facing same problem, have you found any solution?